# Python NameError: "name 'x' is not defined" when used inside for loop

Tags: python, exec

I am trying to run the following file in Python 3.7:

Filename: mytest.py
Contents:

```
def test():
    exec("x=2")
    exec("if x==2: print('yes')")
    exec("[l for l in [1,2,3] if l==x]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

When I run the command:

python3 mytest.py

the first two lines of test() work fine. But the third line gives the following error:

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

The error does not happen if I run the contents of test() directly in the Python Shell or put the contents of test() inside **main**.

Note, in my actual code, I don't know the variable names l and x in advance or the code that needs to inside exec. This is just a simplified example.

Comment: if I run all lines then last works without problem. If I run without first one then second line gives error. So I don't have to run third line to get error. All depends on first line. Python 3.7 / Linux Mint 19.1

Comment: I tested on Python 2.7 - I don't get error if I run first line. I get error in second and third line if I don't use first line.

Comment: Just double check the code in your question is the same as what gave you the error.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me in 2.7 and 3.7! How are you running it?

Comment: Don't use `exec()`. Python is dynamic enough to handle all kinds of changing names.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I realized that the error does not happen if I run the code from Python shell. However, I need to do this from inside a function. I have updated my question accordingly. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

What version of python are you using, tried the same commands on the v3.7 and it executed well

Comment: Thanks. I am using Python 3.7. I realized that the error does not happen if I run the code from Python shell. However, I need to do this from inside a function. I have updated my question accordingly. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by using:

```
globals()['x'] = 2
exec("[l for l in [1,2,3] if l==x]", globals())
```

But this is not a good solution.